# Lever Mechanical Advantage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy-conservation, torque, statics

In the attached image the force output of the plank is calculated to be the work done (F*Df) divided by the height the block rises (Dw). So the force the plank applies on the block is (F*Df)/(Dw). But according to Newton's 3rd Law, this would imply that the block applies a force of (F*Df)/(Dw) on the plank as well.

[image: Lever Mechanical Advantage Calculation]

However, if we analyzed the torques acting on the plank we would find that there would be no NET torque on the plank if the force was (F*Df)/(Dw). That makes me think that the force the plank applies must be slightly less than (F*Df)/(Dw)? How do you explain this concept?

Secondly, how can we assume that all the energy was transmitted solely to the block? What would happen if there was no block? Where would the energy go then?

Comment: Sorry but that diagram is basically unreadable.

Comment: What makes you think there is a net torque on the plank?

Comment: In order to rotationaly accelerate the plank must experience a net a torque

Answer (score 0):

This analysis assumes one of two things.

### No acceleration

If the beam is rotating at a constant velocity, then the fact that there is no net torque on the beam is fine as the net torque is equal to teh moment of inertia times the rotational acceleration $\tau=I\,\alpha$

### No mass

The net torque could also be zero and still allow for acceleration if the mass of the beam is considered negligible.

Comment: But if that assumption were not made, how would you explain the difference between work in and work out?

Comment: @physm12 Then the lever would gain or lose kinetic energy equal to the difference.

Comment: How would you calculate the force output in that case though? And regarding the second question, the plank without the block would stop once one of its ends touches the ground. At this point is all the rotational kinetic energy lost to friction or is converted to potential energy( GPE)? If its converted to potential energy, then when there is a block how come the GPE is not split between the block and the plank?

Comment: @physm12 If there was no block, and the plank had mass, the lever would accelerate at $\frac{\tau}{I}$ gaining kinetic energy until it hit a stop at which point it would rebound with some energy and some of the energy would be turned into hat during the collision.

Comment: What if it were held in place though?

Comment: @physm12 I'm not sure I understand your question. If the lever were held in place by some balancing torque then it wouldn't move... there would be no acceleration and no energy transfer.

Comment: What I mean is if the plank were rotated and then held in place once it could rotate no more?

Comment: @physm12 well then it would undergo a series of micro rebounds each successively smaller until all the energy was turned to heat.

Comment: Wouldn't get potential energy though? What I am trying to understand is why all the energy is gone to the block. Shouln't the lever also acquire some potential energy?

Comment: @physm12 If the lever had mass, and the center of gravity was not centered over the fulcrum, then there would be some change in potential energy. A Teeter Totter lever has the center of mass directly over fulcrum, so when the lever moves, the center of gravity doesn't go up or down. The potential energy gained on one side exactly cancels the potential energy lost on the other side.

Comment: So how come all the work done goes to the block? Why isn't it split between the lever and block?

Comment: @physm12 If the lever had mass, and the center of gravity was not over the fulcrum, then it would be split between the lever and the block.

Comment: So in this case, if the lever has a uniform mass to length density would the plank acquire potential energy? And 2, in a bicycle wheel how is the output force calculated by the input force of the chain on the rear gear? What would be work in and what would be be work out?

Comment: @physm12 It would lose potential energy, because the center of gravity is on the side that moves downward. Ask the bicycle question as a new question (search first to make sure it's not already answered)